# Proving that random variable is independent of a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ such that $$\mathbb{P}(\{X=a\})+ P\mathbb(\{X=b\})=1,$$
>   for some distinct real numbers $a$ and $b$, and $\mathcal{G}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra such that $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$. Also assume that $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})=\mathbb{E}[X].$
>
> Prove that
>
> i. $\mathbb{P}(A \cap G)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(G)$ where $A=\{ \omega \in \Omega:X(\omega)=a \}$ and $G \in \mathcal{G}$.
>
> ii. $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$.

So this is my attempt so far:
If we denote by $B=\{ \omega \in \Omega:X(\omega)=b \}$, we have

$$\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})=a\mathbb{P}(A)+b\mathbb{P}(B)$$

which means that for every $G \in \mathcal{G}$ we have

$$\frac{\mathbb{E}(X 1_{G})}{\mathbb{P}(G)}=a\mathbb{P}(A)+b\mathbb{P}(B)$$

$$\frac{a\mathbb{P}(A\cap G)+b\mathbb{P}(B\cap G)}{\mathbb{P}(G)}=a\mathbb{P}(A)+b\mathbb{P}(B)$$

$$a\mathbb{P}(A| G)+b\mathbb{P}(B| G)=a\mathbb{P}(A)+b\mathbb{P}(B)$$

$$a\mathbb{P}(A| G)+b(1-\mathbb{P}(A| G))=a\mathbb{P}(A)+b(1-\mathbb{P}(A))$$

$$\mathbb{P}(A| G)(a-b)+b=\mathbb{P}(A)(a-b)+b$$

$$\mathbb{P}(A| G)=\mathbb{P}(A)$$

$$\mathbb{P}(A \cap G)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(G)$$

Not sure if it's correct.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until $E(X\mid \mathscr{G}) = aP(A) + bP(B)$ is OK. But write $E(XI_G)/P(G)$ could be meaningless since $G$ could be a zero-probability set, also $P(A \mid G) = 1 - P(B \mid G)$ is not justified. You might proceed as follows:

For each $G \in \mathscr{G}$, since $E[XI_G] = E[I_GE[X \mid \mathscr{G}]]$, we have
$$E[XI_G] = (aP(A) + bP(B))P(G) = (a - b)P(A)P(G) + bP(G). \tag{1}$$
So the problem reduces to evaluate $E[XI_G]$, which is
\begin{align}
& E[XI_G] = \int_G X dP = \int_{G \cap A} X dP + \int_{G \cap B} X dP = aP(G \cap A) + bP(G \cap B) \\
= & aP(G \cap A) + b(P(G) - P(G \cap A)) = (a - b)P(G \cap A) + bP(G). \tag{2}
\end{align}
Equating the right hand sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$ and using the fact $a \neq b$, we conclude that 
$$P(A \cap G) = P(A)P(G)$$
for every $G \in \mathscr{G}$.